# How do you make a dropdown searchbar?

Tags: ios, swift

In the iOS calendar app, when you press the search icon, an animated dropdown containing a search bar is shown, and it instantly gains focus.

## **Before Pressing The Search Icon**

[image: Before]

## **After Pressing The Search Icon**

[image: After]

How would I go about developing a similar search dropdown in my onw app? What sort of classes / methods would I use to achieve this and how would they be put together? Note, I'm sure I could find a third party library to handle this, but I want to know how the could be done using only core iOS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: searchIcon.png)
}

func searchIconTapped() {

    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}
```

To go back to default, just set the `navigationItem.titleView` back to nil